# ComponentListener is not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Please have a look at the following code.

```
package normal;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class MainForm extends JFrame implements ComponentListener
{
    private JTabbedPane tab;

    private InsertForm insertForm;
    private UpdateDeleteForm updateDelete;
    private SearchForm searchForm;

    public MainForm()
    {
        tab = new JTabbedPane();
        insertForm = new InsertForm();
        updateDelete = new UpdateDeleteForm();
        searchForm = new SearchForm();

        //Creating the main window
        tab.add(insertForm,"Insert");
        tab.add(updateDelete,"Update/Delete");
        tab.add(searchForm,"Search");
        tab.addChangeListener(new TabChangeWork());

        getContentPane().add(tab);




       // this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setTitle("My Phone Book App");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.validate();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("X Location: "+this.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    private class TabChangeWork implements ChangeListener
    {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
        {
            JTabbedPane tabSource = (JTabbedPane)e.getSource();

            int index = tabSource.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("Tab Changed to: "+tabSource.getTitleAt(index));


            if(tabSource.getTitleAt(index).equals("Update/Delete"))
            {
                updateDelete.addNames();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In here, the ComponentListener is not working properly because the action inside the method "ComponentMoved" is not happening. I am trying to the get the new coordinates of the JFrame if this is moved. Why it is not working? Please help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have **not registered** with the `ComponentListener` anywhere in the code...

Do it like this....

```
component_to_monitor.addComponentListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not called `addComponentListener` anywhere.

If you wish to register such a listener with your JFrame, then you can add:

```
addComponentListener(this);
```

or, for a sub component, e.g. searchForm:

```
searchForm.addComponentListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `MainForm` is a `ComponentListener`. So it will listen to component events - but only, if you tell it, *where* to listen. Listeners don't listen to anything automatically. They're initially deaf.

Look at the component whose movement you want to monitor and register the main frame with that components `addComponentListner` method.  Something like `component.addComponentListener(this);`